# Typing randomly stops - Lubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

Everything about Lubuntu works great, but I started noticing that typing (as far as I know, it just happens in a web browser) randomly stops.

Here, let me explain better. I use Google Docs religiously. Thus, I type a lot while in a web browser. You know how when you're looking at a page and there's a text field, you click inside the text field to "activate" typing into it. Randomly (sometimes frequently, sometimes rarely) it'll "deactivate" typing as if I've clicked somewhere else, so I need to click inside the text field again to "reactivate" typing.

What could be causing this? I've tested Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Windows 8.1 and it only happens with Lubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will bet that you are using a laptop.  I have had the same thing happen to me.  Your machine may have a setting to disable touchpad while typing that you can cycle on and off.  There is a solution in the Lubuntu wiki.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Mouse#Disable_touchpad_while_typing 
See also 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2212769